# ImportError: No module named ghostscript

Tags: python, python-3.x, ghostscript, importerror, cx-freeze

I get "ImportError: No module named ghostscript" when i try to build my python program using cx_freeze.

- I'm using Windows 7 64 bit
- I have python 3.6.2 **32 bit**
- I installed ghostscript module using pip
- I installed Ghostscript 9.21

Previously, everything worked fine with python 3.6.2 **64 bit**, but now i need to create a 32 bit executable

I'm learning python, so do not omit obvious answers

Comment: Are you using virtualenv  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the .whl file from the link below,

https://pypi.python.org/packages/6a/2d/e2d7474bea24d223d5dc86d51241fd305b75a9168f2e1d7ee07b883c80a5/python3_ghostscript-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl#md5=0e3a24a374c0d9cc1f2008801ead6927

Open cmd in the same directory of the .whl file and run this command:

pip install python3_ghostscript-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl